# How can I build deb packages from ROS2 Bouncy Bolson packages?

Tags: ros2, ros-bouncy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can I use `bloom` to build deb packages from ROS2 Bouncy Bolson packages like [bloom is used to build deb packages from ROS1 packages](https://answers.ros.org/question/173804/generate-deb-from-ros-package/?answer=173845#post-id-173845) ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296624/how-can-i-build-deb-packages-from-ros2-bouncy-bolson-packages?/) by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 468 on 2018-07-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, `bloom` is being used to release ROS 2 packages in (almost) the same way as for ROS 1. Please see these instructions about the differences in setup and which version is needed at least: https://github.com/ros2/ros2/wiki/Releasing-a-ROS-2-package-with-bloom

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2018-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0